# Question on proof of $\mathrm{rank}(A^*A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Here $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose. I've found other questions with nice answers on the $A^t$ version but with distinctly different proofs than the one I outline below. I'm curious if someone could enlighten me on the first equality below (in the main proof section) I think its something simple I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

**Lemma:** Let $A\in$ $m\times n$ Matrix with $x\in$ $F^n$ and $y\in$ $F^m$. Then

$\langle Ax,y\rangle_m=\langle x,A^*y\rangle_n$

Where $\langle\rangle$ denotes an inner product, with respect to $F^n$ and $F^m$ using the subscripts.

**Main Proof:**

The proof itself uses the dimension theorem after showing that $A^*$ and $A$ have the same null space.

The equality I'm struggling with is:

$\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle_n=\langle Ax, A^{**}x\rangle_m$

If someone could explain it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for properly formatting your posts.

Answer (score 1):

We already know that:
$$\langle Cy,z\rangle_n = \langle y, C^* z\rangle_m$$
Now, let $C = A^*$, $y = Ax$ (which is a vector), and $z = x$.  Then, we get that:
$$\langle (A^*)(Ax),x\rangle_n = \langle Ax, (A^*)^* x\rangle_m$$
Getting rid of parenthesis where we can, we have that:
$$\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle_n = \langle Ax,A^{**}x\rangle_m$$
as desired.

Comment: oops, m and n are arbitrary! thanks!